# Spring cloud gateway route with multiple instances and sticky session

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm pretty much new to spring cloud gateway. I have configured routing with two different apps with 'path'. Now, I need some help/docs on

```
1. How to route to different instance of an app from spring cloud gateway?
2. How to enable sticky session?
```

My apps are not using spring boot/eureka. I do see that I can use lb://service-name if i'm using any discovery client (unfortunately that is not my case).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to Two different instance ? under some LB? without service registry and discoveryclient you can not use lb://service-name based url. You need to give the exact url in uri part of mapping if instances are running on different port

Answer (score 1):

IMHO:

> 1. How to route to different instance of an app from spring cloud gateway?

Routing to different instances is the basic job of what spring cloud gateway is doing. Spring cloud gateway implements the pattern named **client side routing** along with the ease of **service discovery**. So if you are not using any discovery server or your apps are not registered with any discovery server, you loose the dynamic discovery and routing feature, BUT still you can specify your server list (refer to Netflix Ribbon). Until then you can think about your routing strategy.

> 2. How to enable sticky session?

I suppose that's one requirement of your routing strategy - implement sticky session because you are not using **shared** session store. According to my limited knowledge of spring cloud gateway, sticky seems not being supported out of box. But it could be customized with a **Filter**, see shipped **LoadBalancerClientFilter** for reference.

Good luck!